# windowSoftInputMode adjustPan: How to add more margin to text field of DatePicker (spinner mode)

Tags: android, focus, adjustpan

I want to activity have an offset as spinner container when textfield recieve focus.

What I want to achieve:

[image: 1]

What I get:

[image: 2]

How can I acheive desired behaviour? Is there a way to wrap any view in container that `adjustPan` will respect?

Answer (score -1):

Set `windowSoftInputMode` property to `adjustResize`

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

Comment: No, its not suitable for me. I dont want to rearrange UI.